# Dont require passwords on user creation form

Tags: django-forms, django-admin, django-users

Because I am using windows authentication for my site, When an admin is creating users through the admin site, I would like the password fields in the UserCreationForm to be to be optional, or better yet, to not be there at all.

I have tried setting `self.fields['password1'].required = False` and likewise for 'password2'. I have also seen some people using `set_unusable_password()` But I am not sure where I am supposed to put it (right now I have it in my proxy user model, in the init method.

```
class DomainUser(User):
        class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_unusable_password()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need the password fields in the add user form of the admin site to be optional, not Mandatory